# Regular expression for file path which doesn't allow parent directories

Tags: regex, bash, filepath

I'm looking to write a regex for a file path that must start with some prefix. In this case it should start with '/tank/home/'. I also want to make sure that it contains no '/..' -- no jumping up to parent directories.

I spent a while fiddling around without coming up with anything quite right. I settled on using two regexes, the first which must match and the second which must not match:

```
'^/tank/home/'

'/\.\.(/.*)?$'
```

Does this do what I think it does? Is there an easier way?

This is in a bash script, for what it's worth.

Comment: Actually `[^\.\.]` wouldn't match _any_ path with a dot in it, as `[]` is a character group.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that after posting. Edited to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can expand Dav's regex to include an extra trailing slash:

```
^(?!.*/\.\./.*)/tank/home.*$
```

But... a better option might be to make sure that the result of the path is something that starts under /tank/home:

```
FILEPATH=$(readlink -f $YOURFILE)
[[ $FILEPATH =~ ^/tank/home/ ]] && echo "starts with /tank/home/"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead to make sure that there aren't any `/..` in the string:

```
^(?!.*/\.\..*)/tank/home.*$
```

Comment: Very close, but not quite right. That doesn't match "/tank/home/..foo".

Comment: If it's really necessary that you be able to match ..foo, then something like this should probably work: `^(?!.*/\.\.(?:/.*|$))/tank/home.*$`

Comment: (Basically make the look-ahead only match if it's /../ or /.. at the end of the string.)

Comment: Thanks -- I hadn't used negative lookahead before.

Answer (score 1):

```
'^/tank/home(?!.*/\.\.(/|$))/'
```

matches /tank/home/foo..bar but not /tank/home/.. or /tank/home/foo/../bar

Answer (score 0):

You could use negative lookbehind too:

```bash
\/tank\/home\/([^\/]|?(&lt;!\/\.\.)\/)+$
```