# regex to capture all file paths not containing directory links

Tags: regex, validation, path

I am trying to write a regular expression to match file paths with the following characteristics:

1. do not contain `/./` or `/../`
2. must be nested at least one subdirectory deep within `/tmp/media`
3. must end in `.log`

[Here](http://rubular.com/r/3w69wjvMck) is what I have so far:

```
\/tmp\/media\/(?!.*\.?\.\/)+(?:.*\.log)
```

Here are my desired results (if the string doesn't match, I cite the requirement which is not satisfied):

```
/tmp/media/log.log             //NO-MATCH (2)
/tmp/media/test/log.log        //MATCH
/tmp/media/../log.log          //NO-MATCH (1)
/tmp/media/./log.log           //NO-MATCH (1)
/tmp/media/test/../log.log     //NO-MATCH (1)
/tmp/media/../test/log.log     //NO-MATCH (1)
/tmp/media/.t/log.log          //MATCH
/tmp/media/.../log.log         //MATCH
/tmp/log.log                   //NO-MATCH (2)
/tmp/media/test/log.notlog     //NO-MATCH (3)
/tmp/media/test/./log.log      //NO-MATCH (1)
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1242204/regular-expression-for-file-path-which-doesnt-allow-parent-directories), and successfully implemented some of the answer, but /tmp/media/log.log is still matching when I do not want it to. I suspect it is because the empty string between `/media/` and `log.log` somehow satisfies `(?!.*\.?\.\/)`.

Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong and help me correct my expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
^(?![^.]*\/\.\.?\/)\/tmp\/media\/(?:[^\/]+)*\/\w+\.log$
```

[**rubular link**](http://www.rubular.com/r/3XUvjaOLUm)

Comment: This also seems to match `/tmp/media//log.log`... I did not specify it in my requirements, but I should have mentioned that I want only legal file paths.

Comment: `/tmp/media//log.log` actually is legal - take a look at this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. Intuition said otherwise :)

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to be a regexp? As suggested in the link you provided, you can use readlink. Also, it would be easier to just check for `/./` and `/../` before doing the regex matching for other constraints - would make your code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

You should *really* canonize your paths first.  This will avoid attempting to block `.` and `..` directories in the regex itself.  Once you have done that, the regex becomes:

```
\/tmp\/media\/[^\/]+\/.*\.log
```

Without knowing which language you are programming in, I cannot suggest a path-canonization mechanism.

Comment: I am using this in Qt. Basically it's for initializing a highly-customized file browser view that is intended to prevent the user from navigating up a directory from /tmp/media.

Comment: @burpen: Qt is not a programming language.

Comment: Alright, to split hairs, it's C++, but I'm using Qt's QRegExp class: http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qregexp.html

Comment: In that case, I would recommend using `realpath()` to canonize the pathname, followed by a more sane regular expression.